# PFQuery not running after Swift 3 conversion

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift3, parse-server

I migrated to Swift 3 and have updated all my Parse functions to the latest syntax. Now, none of the queries return anything. There is no no error but there are also no objects. Whats weird is that it doesn't look like its even making a call, as it instantly returns no objects and there is no activity indicator spinning in the status bar like usual. Here's the query code:

```
   let profileQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    profileQuery.whereKey("emailLowercase", equalTo: emailField.text!.lowercased() as String)
    profileQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in


        print(objects?.count)

   })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it as such:

```
            let Query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
                Query.whereKey("emailLowercase", equalTo: emailField.text!.lowercased() as String)
                Query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in

                  if (error == nil) {
                    print("Success")
                    print(objects?.count)
                  } else {
                    print("Error")
                  }
               })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Same issue though. Error is nil but so are the number of objects (i know there should be 1). Still the same issue where it looks like the query doesn't even make a call (instantly returns nil and no spinning wheel)

Comment: mmm, then i think you need to dig deeper and insure there is a instance that the server is running etc. Check and make sure the parse library is added correct.

Comment: Not completely relevant, but it might be time to start considering other platforms over Parse. The Android & iOS SDKs have had almost no development over the past few months.

Answer (score 0):

Your query code should be like this;

```
let query = PFUser.query()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with your  as Baris has suggest is that you are querying the class wrong. You can't query with ("_User")

```
let profileQuery =  PFUser.query()
profileQuery.whereKey("emailLowercase", equalTo: emailField.text!.lowercased() as String)
profileQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
  if error == nil{
    print(objects?.count)
  }
})
```